# What does mongo's db.stats().ok means?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, statistics, nosql

There is no documentation on what `db.stats().ok` means on mongodb's site https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.stats/.

For example I would like to check if the connection to the database is healthy. Can I do it like that `db.stats().ok === 1`. Is that correct for my purpose (looks like it, but without docs it's hard to tell), also is there a better way of checking for a healthy mongo connection?

Comment: Documentation for `ok` (part of the command response) is [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/use-database-commands/#command-responses)

Comment: Welp thanks, that's pretty wacky considering that I am not sure if that explanation is useful for what I am trying to do, but at least is something. I still cannot tell, if ok can be equal to 1 both for healthy and unhealthy mongo connection. Also where they put that reference is blowing my mind.

Comment: What do you mean by "checking for a healthy mongo connection"? If your connection fails then your application should throw an error immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `db.getMongo()`. Command `db.stats()` requires read permissions on current database, which could be missing. In such case `db.stats()` would fail, despite your MongoDB is running fine.

`db.getMongo()` does not require any privileges, you can connect even without any credentials!

```
mongosh "mongodb://localhost:27017" --norc --quiet --eval 'db.getMongo()'
mongodb://localhost:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.6.0
echo $?
0

$ mongosh "mongodb://xxxx:27017" --norc --quiet --eval 'db.getMongo()'
MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND xxxx
echo $?
1
```